# Postgresql PSQL sequence stare-down. Why does this not execute to completion?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm in psql trying to create a table for a python admin. It's actually an extension of a working admin, so I'm adding a new table and some relations. When I enter in the following sequence, it never executes to completion:

```
BEGIN;

   CREATE TABLE "work_projectinteractiveasset" (
     "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
     "image" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
     "project_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "work_project" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
   );

    CREATE INDEX "work_projectinteractiveasset_project_id" 
        ON "work_projectinteractiveasset" ("project_id");

COMMIT;
```

The prompt ends with

> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "work_projectinteractiveasset_id_seq" for serial column "work_projectinteractiveasset.id"

But it just stays there until I ctrl-c out of it. Is there some way to force the completion?

Comment: After adding `create table work_project ( id serial primary key );`, this runs without errors my installation of PostgreSQL 8.2.  I suspect there is something external to these queries at play.

Comment: @Pythovore: What version of Postgres are you using?  The alternative would be to not use the `serial` keyword and setup the sequence manually

Comment: "NOT NULL" is redundant with "PRIMARY KEY" (but that's not your problem).  Which line is it stuck on?  That is, what happens when you comment-out the CREATE INDEX?  Do you have a long-running transaction somewhere (e.g., another psql session where you typed "begin", did something to that table, and never typed either "abort" or "commit")?

Comment: The alter table will hang, too.  You've got a long-running transaction somewhere.  The task is to find it.  ptop (http://ptop.projects.postgresql.org/) might help you to discover it.

Comment: Yes that is it! There is a stuck transaction that needs to be killed. Thanks to all!  Only 6 gray hairs this time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not actually able to produce this error. However what it sounds like is you have a lock  that is stopping the work from completing.

```
 postgres=# create table work_project (id int primary key);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "work_project_pkey" for table "work_project"
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
postgres=# 
postgres=#    CREATE TABLE "work_projectinteractiveasset" (
postgres(#      "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
postgres(#      "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
postgres(#      "image" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
postgres(#      "project_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "work_project" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
postgres(#    );
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "work_projectinteractiveasset_id_seq" for serial column "work_projectinteractiveasset.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "work_projectinteractiveasset_pkey" for table "work_projectinteractiveasset"
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# 
postgres=#     CREATE INDEX "work_projectinteractiveasset_project_id" 
postgres-#         ON "work_projectinteractiveasset" ("project_id");
CREATE INDEX
postgres=# 
postgres=# COMMIT;
COMMIT
```

postgres=# select version();

### version

PostgreSQL 8.3.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.4.real (Ubuntu 4.4.1-3ubuntu3) 4.4.1
(1 row)